# setHasFixedSize(true) making the app crash

Tags: java, android

When I run the app and go to the user's activity the app crashes showing me that the mUsersList.setHasFixedSize(true); is making the app crash.

this is the message "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference"

```
private RecyclerView mUsersList;
private DatabaseReference mUsersDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.users_single_layout);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");




    mUsersList = findViewById(R.id.users_list);
    mUsersList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mUsersList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The layout users_single_layout that you inflate does not contain a view with id: `users_list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace tells you everything you need.  mUsersList is null, so you can't call any methods on it.  You should make sure your layout file `R.layout.users_single_layout` has a RecyclerView with id of "@+id/users_list" defined in it.  Also, you should do a null pointer check:

```
mUsersList = findViewById(R.id.users_list);
if (mUsersList != null) {
    mUsersList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mUsersList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}
```

Comment: oh yeah i forgot to check the setcontentview.. thanks